# how to calculate $\sum^{n}_{k=m}\binom{k}{m}\binom{n}{k}$?

Tags: binomial-coefficients

> For natural numbers $m \leq n$ calculate (i.e. express by a simple formula
>   not containing a sum)
>   $$\sum^{n}_{k=m}\binom{k}{m}\binom{n}{k}.$$

I searched and answer is probably

$=\binom{n}{m}\sum^{n}_{k=m}\binom{n-m}{n-k}$

$=\binom{n}{m}\sum^{n-m}_{k=0}\binom{n-m}{k}$

$=\binom{n}{m}2^{n-m}$

Q

1: Is the answer correct?

2: Why take $\binom{n}{m}$ in front of sum?

3: How to transform the first formula to become second formula?

Comment: Combinatorial interpretation: You have n ppl and you need to form a committee. The committee needs to have m board members. We can either first pick the committee members and then pick the board members out of them which gives you the sum. Alternatively, you can pick the board members first, which gives $\binom{n}m$. Then the rest of the committee comes from the n-m people, of which there are $2^{n-m}$ choices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\binom{k}m\binom{n}k=\frac{k!}{m!(k-m)!}\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}=\frac{n!}{m!(k-m)!(n-k)!}=$$$$\frac{n!(n-m)!}{m!(n-m)!(k-m)!(n-k)!}=\binom{n}{m}\binom{n-m}{n-k}$$

$\binom{n}{m}$ can be taken in front because it does not depend on index $k$.

Comment: I understood. And why can $\sum^{n}_{k=m}$ transform $\sum^{n-m}_{k=0}$ ?

Comment: $\binom{n-m}{n-m}+\cdots+\binom{n-m}0=\binom{n-m}0+\cdots+\binom{n-m}{n-m}$.

Comment: if so why $\binom{n-m}{n-k}$ transform $\binom{n-m}{k}$  ?

Comment: Those expression are not equal  (and nobody says they are)

Comment: so is $\sum^{n}_{k=m}\binom{n-m}{n-k}$ = $\sum^{n-m}_{k=0}\binom{n-m}{k}$  wrong ?

Comment: No, it is correct,  but does not rest on equality of the expressions mentioned in your former comment.

Comment: I'm sorry, my writing might have confused you. What I meant to was why $\sum^{n}_{k=m}\binom{n-m}{n-k}$ transform $\sum^{n-m}_{k=0}\binom{n-m}{k}$.

Comment: I already answered that in my first comment. Do you agree that $\sum_{k=m}^{n}\binom{n-m}{n-k}=\binom{n-m}{n-m}+\cdots+\binom{n-m}{0}$
and that$\sum_{k=0}^{n-m}\binom{n-m}{k}=\binom{n-m}{0}+\cdots+\binom{n-m}{n-m}$
so that the expressions are equal? The second expression is on its
turn equal to $\sum_{k=0}^{n-m}\binom{n-m}{k}1^{k}1^{n-m-k}=2^{n-m}$.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

It is sufficient to answer (3).

> We obtain for integral $0\leq m\leq n$:
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=m}^n\binom{k}{m}\binom{n}{k}}&=\sum_{k=m}^n\binom{n}{m}\binom{n-m}{n-k}\tag{1}\\
> &=\binom{n}{m}\sum_{k=m}^n\binom{n-m}{n-k}\tag{2}\\
> &=\binom{n}{m}\sum_{k=0}^{n-m}\binom{n-m}{n-(k+m)}\tag{3}\\
> &=\binom{n}{m}\sum_{k=0}^{n-m}\binom{n-m}{k}\tag{4}\\
> &=\binom{n}{m}\sum_{k=0}^{n-m}\binom{n-m}{k}1^k1^{n-m-k}\\
> &=\binom{n}{m}(1+1)^{n-m}\tag{5}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\binom{n}{m}2^{n-m}}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the binomial identity $\binom{k}{m}\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{m}\binom{n-m}{n-k}$.
- In (2) we factor out $\binom{n}{m}$ which does not depend on the index $k$.
- In (3) we shift the index to start with $k=0$. To compensate the index-shift $k\to k-m$ we replace in the summand $k$ with $k+m$.
- In (4) we use the binomial identity $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p}{p-q}$.
- In (5) we apply the binomial theorem.